# Last entered date irrespective of subject

Tags: sql, t-sql

Thanks for you help in advance,
I have an query which appsolutly works fine but my requirement is to find the student last entry date irrespective of subject

Many Thanks

```
WITH T_Subjects AS 
(  
SELECT T_Student_History.StudenID,  
Convert(varchar(11), MAX(T_Student_History.Created),101)AS 'Student Last entry',  
'History' AS 'Subject Name'   
FROM T_Student_History   
Group BY T_Student_History.StudentID  
UNION ALL  

SELECT T_Student_geography.StudentID,  
Convert(varchar(11), MAX(T_Student_geography.Created),101)AS 'Student Last entry',  
'Geography' AS 'Subject Name'   
FROM T_Student_geography  
Group BY T_Student_geography.StudentID  
Union ALL  

SELECT T_Student_Computing.StudentID,  
Convert(varchar(11), MAX(T_Student_Computing.Created),101)AS 'Student Last entry',  
'Computing' AS 'Subject Name'   
FROM  T_Student_Computing  
Group BY  T_Student_Computing.StudentID  
) 

SELECT   
T_Students.StudentID 
T_Students.Forename+' '+T_Students.Surname AS 'Student Description',                   
T_Students.Email, 
T_Students.Mobile, 
T_Subjects.StudentLastEntry  
T_Subjects.Subject Name 
FROM T_Students  
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_Subjects ON T_Students.StudentID = T_Subjects.StudentID
```

Comment: Do you want to include the name of the subject that is latest for the student, as well as the date itself? If so, how do you want to deal with the possibility that more than one subject may have the same last entry date?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response,As you see there are 3 different subjects computing,geography,history I just want to know which last subject student enroll

Comment: If student enroll more than one subject in the same day, I want to see all of that last day.

Comment: Do you want just the results for the student with the last entry date, or do you want results to include every student?

Comment: I want the results for the student with the last entry date for every student

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the query below will get you what you want. If multiple students are tied for last entry, then it will return all of them. I fixed some minor issues, and then added the last few lines, the WHERE clause.

```
    WITH  T_Subjects
        AS ( SELECT  T_Student_History.StudentID ,  --Typo here?
                     MAX(T_Student_History.Created) AS [Student Last entry] ,
                     'History' AS [Subject Name]
             FROM    T_Student_History
             GROUP BY T_Student_History.StudentID
             UNION ALL
             SELECT  T_Student_geography.StudentID ,
                     MAX(T_Student_geography.Created) AS [Student Last entry] ,
                     'Geography' AS [Subject Name]
             FROM    T_Student_geography
             GROUP BY T_Student_geography.StudentID
             UNION ALL
             SELECT  T_Student_Computing.StudentID ,
                     MAX(T_Student_Computing.Created) AS [Student Last entry] ,
                     'Computing' AS [Subject Name]
             FROM    T_Student_Computing
             GROUP BY T_Student_Computing.StudentID
           )
   SELECT   T_Students.StudentID ,
            T_Students.Forename + ' ' + T_Students.Surname AS [Student Description] ,
            T_Students.Email ,
            T_Students.Mobile ,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), T_Subjects.[Student Last Entry], 101) AS [Student Last Entry],
          -- Do you really want the above as a String and not a date?
            T_Subjects.[Student Last Entry] ,
            T_Subjects.[Subject Name]
   FROM     T_Students
   LEFT OUTER JOIN T_Subjects
            ON T_Students.StudentID = T_Subjects.StudentID
   WHERE    T_Subjects.[Student Last Entry] = ( SELECT MAX([Student Last Entry])
                                                FROM     T_Subjects ts2
                                                WHERE    ts2.StudentID = T_Students.StudentID
                                          )
```

Comment: Thanks for you response but i want the student last entry enrollment date based on studentid

Answer (score 3):

This is a good use for [ranking window functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx).

Suppose you define `T_Subject` more-or-less as you already have:

```
  SELECT StudentID,
         MAX(Created) AS [Created],
         'Whatever' AS [Subject Name]
    FROM T_Student_Whatever
GROUP BY StudentID
   UNION ALL
  SELECT ... and so on for each T_Student_Foo...
```

You can then get the most recent subject enrollment (you call it "Student Last Entry") per StudentID with:

```
SELECT StudentID,
       Created,
       [Subject Name]
  FROM (SELECT T_Subjects.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY Created DESC)
                 AS [ranking] -- rank subject enrollment by recency
          FROM T_Subjects)
 WHERE ranking = 1            -- now select only the first ranked per StudentID
```

And you can then join *that* query with your `T_Students` table to fetch names and mobile numbers, etc.

### Update 2011-10-20

It's not entirely clear what the OP is looking for, but `RANK()` rather than `ROW_NUMBER()` may be preferred.  The former will duplicate rankings on equivalent partition characteristics, that is, records can "tie" for Nth place.

For example, assuming the student with ID #1 most recently took both Computing and History yesterday, but student #2 most recently took Computing two weeks ago, the difference would be:

```
[ RANK()d ]
 StudentID | StudentLastEntry | SubjectName
-----------+------------------+-------------
         1 |       2011-10-19 | Computing
         1 |       2011-10-19 | History
         2 |       2011-10-06 | Computing
```

versus for example

```
[ ROW_NUMBER()d ]
 StudentID | StudentLastEntry | SubjectName
-----------+------------------+-------------
         1 |       2011-10-19 | History       -- or 'Computing'
         2 |       2011-10-06 | Computing
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, I am trying to understand this query, Can you please let me know about ranking

Comment: `RANK()` and friends will change the way you look at many common SQL tasks.  Follow the MSDN link I gave, or google for "SQL analytic functions" or "SQL window functions" -- or ask StackOverflow for good tutorials! :)

Comment: Sorry, I cant run your query,Can you give me the proper query please

Comment: For this solution, I think you'd want to use ROW_NUMBER() rather than RANK() to avoid duplicate rows in case of ties (same Created value).  But, I think you're better off using MAX() as I did in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Even easier, you can use the Over() with MAX.  Try this in your final SELECT

```
MAX(T_Subjects.StudentLastEntry) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY T_Subjects.StudentID) AS StudentLastEntry
```

Many people know about using OVER and PARTITION BY with ranking functions, but you can also use it with other aggregates like MAX and COUNT.

Comment: Yes, this is just one column entry for the resultset.  The others are independent.  Instead of just returning the T_Subjects.StudentLastEntry for each row, use this column specification instead and get the max for this StudentID.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow and I don't see how you pin the correct Subject -- SubjectName is not independent of StudentID and StudentLastEntry.  If Student 5 took History on $TODAY but Computing $YESTERDAY, we don't want to see (5, 'Computing', $TODAY) ...

Comment: I think that's what he does want to see.  The maximum date for that student irrespective of subject name.  Look at the title of this post.

Comment: Yes, but see the first clarifying comment by the OP.  Hmm.  It also appears that the OP wants RANK behavior, not ROW_NUMBER, given a later comment.

Comment: You may be right.  I don't really know what he wants anymore.  This requires a clearer statement of the problem, or sample data and results that answer the ambiguities.  From the problem statement, I thought it would be a good example to showcase the MAX() OVER() syntax. :-)

Comment: I just want to see only last enrollment based studentid not all

Comment: Okay, then you should use pilcrow's solution.  If you prefer to use CTEs over derived tables, you can create another CTE with the same definition as his derived table, and select from that (keep the same WHERE clause).